# What is the best way to parse MadExcept bugreports sent to a datasnap server?

Tags: delphi, mime, datasnap, madexcept

I configured a datasnap rest server as a custom script upload location for madexcept.

Everything works fine up to the part where I try to parse the variables set in the report. They were added with

```
MESettings.AdditionalFields.Add('appname', '%appname%')
```

I recognized that the report is sent as **multipart/form-data**, therefore I tried including **Web.ReqMulti** into my unit to get the parsed with **TMultipartContentParser**
It looks like this in the REST-method

```
function V1RestMethod.UpdateBugReport: TJSONArray;
var
  LReq:TWebRequest; 
  LAppName:string;   
begin
  LReq:=GetDataSnapWebModule.Request;
  LAppName:= LReq.ContentFields.Values['appname'];  
end;
```

At this point, `LAppName` is empty since `LReq.ContentFields.Count` is 0

What would be the recommended way of parsing this bugreport?

**Update_1:**

It seems that the TMultipartContentParser seems to correctly parse all files (`application/octet-stream`) but leaves the plaintext unparsed.

Comment: Do you have any intention of making the tool open source or link to further guidance? A blog post maybe?

Comment: @Gogowitsch Unfortunately not, since it's work related code :(